# Validate double number in current culture

Tags: c#, parsing, double, cultureinfo, currentculture

There is a way to validate a double number in the current culture? I have tried this:

```
var number ="10,10";
double value = double.Parse(number,
                    NumberStyles.Float, 
                    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

If I try this with "es-ES" (where decimal separator is ",") then the parsing works perfect, I got an double `10.10`, but if I try with "en-US" (where decimal separator is ".") the parsing can't understand the decimal point, so just omit it, so I get a `1010` incorrect number.

There is a way for me to get an exception when I tried to convert a wrong number for the specified culture?

Edit: by "," I don't mean thousand separator, I mean the decimal separator for some cultures like es-ES

Comment: No, because you have to know the meaning of `"10,10"`. So you etiher have to rely on `CurrentCulture` or know what was used originally.

Comment: I know what is the CurrentCulture in use, but insted of usting the right format, I'm inserting a wrong one, I should not been able to cast one culture to another, I just want an error to pop up, not a failed conversion

Comment: How about double.TryParse?

Comment: The group-separator is not used if you specify `NumberStyles.Float`, so `10,10` should not be interpreted as the group-separator in "en-US". Instead you get an exception as desired.

Comment: Like @TimSchmelter said, nothing will work with 100% certainty - 100.000 and 100,000 could be the same number depending on what the _source_ culture is.  If you're formatting the number to a string based on the client culture, then you have to know the client culture to parse it back to a number.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear in the question, I will clarify, when I use "," is not thousand separator, is decimal separator for some cultures i.e. es-ES, I dont want to have the thousand separator, I just want to try parse "10,10" with en-US culture and get an error

Comment: @Balder Then you have to disallow thousands separators.  If you allow thousands separators then parsing `10,10` in en-US will not generate an error.  However then you can't parse `12.345,67` in ANY culture

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my machine the following throws a FormatException, as expected:

```
var number ="10,10";
double value = double.Parse(number,
NumberStyles.Float, 
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I suspect you're using `NumberStyles.AllowThousands`.  For example, the following will return 1010:

```
var number ="10,10";
double value = double.Parse(number,
NumberStyles.Float | NumberStyles.AllowThousands, 
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

**UPDATE**

in response to comment:

> ... but if I'm using en-US "10,10" becames "1010" instead of throwing an error

That's not what I'd expect; for example, the following will throw a `FormatException`:

```
var number ="10,10";
double value = double.Parse(number,
NumberStyles.Float, 
new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Comment: Yes, that is true, because "," is not a valid separator in InvariantCulture however I use several cultures to render my application, if I'm using es-ES "10,10" turns in 10.10, but if I'm using en-US "10,10" becames "1010" instead of throwing an error (which is what i want)